# JavaScript create dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I am working on a system where customer needs to create forms(questionnaire) for users. Each user will have same questions. Customer needs to create multiple questionnaire each day or week so he wants to make it more automated and of course he doesn't know about HTML and css that much.

My question is there any way for him to add questions and create templates automatically.

Here how questions could be.

```
Q: What are your current important goals?
Answer: (Now this will be textarea)

Q: How are feeling today?
Answer: (This would have many radio buttons)
```

So is there any way to provide such facility where he can simply drag and drop form elements and it is created. Also this form will be saved and will be populated for each user and each user would have their own answers.

Comment: In terms of the UI/UX, you could use Google Form creation as a reference. However, as it stands your question is probably too broad in scope to be answered on this site, as there are many (equally valid) ways to approach and implement what you want.

Comment: Or you need to create a API that generate standardized forms with a form generation process

Comment: At the moment customer provide us with pdf file and we convert it into md file by hand and at the end of each question a word is mentioned to describe what kind of input field is to be populated but now he wants to make it possible to create by himself. So every time he needs to create a form he provide us with pdf file.

Comment: And googel form is exactly what I have in mind. But is there any other way to generate such template with javascript plugin.

Comment: A quick Google search for "form builder js plugin" turned up [what you seem to be looking for](https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder).